# Fixed point for a map from $\{0,1\}^N$ to itself

Tags: co.combinatorics, fixed-point-theorems

Let $N\geq2.$ Let $F$ be a function from $\left\{ 0,1\right\} ^{N}$ to itself
dreceasing for the product order defined by $$ (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)\leq (y_1,\ldots,y_N)\  \text{  if and only if for all }i,\ x_i\leq y_i $$

Here, $F$ being decreasing means $$x\leq y \Rightarrow F(y)\leq F(x)$$

Suppose moreover that the $i^{th}$ component of $F$
does not depend on the $i^{th}$ variable.

Is it true that $F$ has a unique
fixed point ?

Comment: It is for N=2. Just check all the possible $F$

Comment: This question looks interesting. Can you write more explicitly what you mean by "the i.th component does not depend on the i.th variable"?

Comment: I.e., there is a function $F_i$ such that $F(x)_i = F_i(x_1, \dotsc, x_{i - 1}, \widehat{x_i}, x_{i + 1}, \dotsc, x_N)$?

Comment: No, the order is the product order which is only a partial order: $$(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N)\leq(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_N)$$ if and only $$x_i\leq y_i$$ for all i=1..N. Moreover, LSpice is correct. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Do you mean order preserving or f(x)\leq x or what does decreasing Mean?

Comment: Some others comments : if you remove one of the two hypothesis, the result is wrong even for $N=2$. Moreover, I have an algorithm that produces a lot of examples of such $F$ for which the proposition was always satisified.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg : decreasing in the standard sense for the order product : if $x\leq y$ then $F(x)\geq F(y)$.

Comment: Iterating $F$ starting from $(1,\dots,1)$ one arrives in $\le 2^N$ iterations to a stationary point, or no?

Comment: @Pietro Majer : can you develop ? Because $F(x)\leq x $ is not necessarly satisfied.

Comment: But doesn't $x^1 \le x^0:=(1,\dots,1)$ imply $x^2\le x^1\le x^0$ etc? ($x^k:=F^{(k)}(x^0)$)

Comment: Nope. $x^2\leq x^0$ because $(1,...1)$ is the max of the whole set but there is no need for $x^2$ to be smaller than $x^1$

Comment: I see,  I understood that  $x^2=F(x^1)\le F(x^0)=x^1$  because $F$ respects the order of $x^1\le x^0$

Comment: @Yoyo: you claim that “$F(x)\le x$ is not necessarily satisfied”. If so, then what do you mean by “$F$ is decreasing for the product order” other than $F(x)\le x$ when you have explained that the product order $(x_1,\ldots,x_N)\le(y_1,\ldots,y_N)$ simply means $x_i\le y_i$ for all $i$!.....Adding a clear-cut example in the question could help.

Comment: Well $F$ is decreasing so, precisely, it switches the order.

Comment: @Jack L : for me, a decreasing function means : if $x\leq y$ then $F(x) \geq F(y)$.

Comment: Ok, so at least  $F^2$ is increasing, so it has a fixed point for the above argument, that is a period 2 point of F. Maybe one can show that $F^2$ has an odd number of fixed points, so one is also fixed for F

Comment: @PietroMajer : nice idea !

Comment: Okay, my attempt will be to endow $M:=\{0,1\}^N$ with a complete metric such that $F$ is a contraction (or, compact metric such that $F$ is a contractive map). Fixed point theorems due to Banach and Edelstein would then give you a unique fixed point (plus all iterates converging to it in the defined metric).

Comment: I think order reversing is more common for this phenomenon.  For order preserving you could use the Tarski fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 6):

For $N = 3$ there are exactly $58$ counterexamples.

$54$ of them have two fixed points. E.g.:
\begin{eqnarray}
000 &\mapsto& 110\\
100 &\mapsto& 100\\
010 &\mapsto& 010\\
110 &\mapsto& 000\\
001 &\mapsto& 000\\
101 &\mapsto& 000\\
011 &\mapsto& 000\\
111 &\mapsto& 000\\
\end{eqnarray}

$2$ of them have three fixed points. E.g.:

\begin{eqnarray}
000 &\mapsto& 111\\
100 &\mapsto& 100\\
010 &\mapsto& 010\\
110 &\mapsto& 000\\
001 &\mapsto& 001\\
101 &\mapsto& 000\\
011 &\mapsto& 000\\
111 &\mapsto& 000\\
\end{eqnarray}

2 of them have zero fixed point. E.g.:
\begin{eqnarray}
000 &\mapsto& 111\\
100 &\mapsto& 101\\
010 &\mapsto& 110\\
110 &\mapsto& 100\\
001 &\mapsto& 011\\
101 &\mapsto& 001\\
011 &\mapsto& 010\\
111 &\mapsto& 000\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: In fact, from the first four rows of your first counterexample we see that it's not true for $N = 2$ either.

Comment: @lambda Yes, not sure whether I'm missing something, as the OP claims that it's true for $N = 2$.

Comment: Thx for your contribution.Have to think about it a bit more...

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider
$$F(0)=7,\ F(1)=5,\ F(2)=3,\ F(3)=1$$
$$F(4)=6,\ F(5)=4,\ F(6)=2,\ F(7)=0$$
where a number represents its base-2 expansion, e.g. 6 represents $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: I fixed the answer; now it is decreasing where before it was non-decreasing.